# Far star in CGSuite

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I've calculated some games by using CGSuite.

I would like to input the far star (=remote star) in CGSuite, but I don't know the word for the far star.

Could you let me know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote star (I'll use $\bigstar$) is not a particular game, it's a shorthand notation that suppresses quantifiers.

For example, Definition II.7.4 of "Combinatorial Game Theory" by Aaron Siegel (also the author of CGSuite) says:

> For all $G$ and $H$: $G\sim H$ if $o(G+X+\bigstar)=o(H+X+\bigstar)$ for all $X$... Here the expression...is shorthand for $o(G+X+*m)=o(H+X+*m)$ for all sufficiently large $m$, with the understanding that the meaning of "sufficiently large" depends on the choice of $X$.

So even if you're working with particular games $G$ and $H$, there's not a single game (a "remote star in context"?) that, say, witnesses $G\sim H$, because of the dependence on $X$. That's why it would be a little unlikely for CGSuite to have $\bigstar$.

That said, depending on what you're looking at, maybe just using $*100$ where you wanted to use $\bigstar$ would suffice for all of your calculations.